# Unable to play videostreams generated by videosnarf

Tags: video-processing

I have wireshark capturing video call between two of my IP call clients. I've generated video streams using videosnarf tool by giving pcap as input. But when I try to play them with ffplay they are not being played.

ffplay H264-media-4.264

ffplay version 4.1.3-0york1~16.04 Copyright (c) 2003-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='0york1~16.04' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared

libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100

[h264 @ 0x7f3158000940] Format h264 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!

[h264 @ 0x7f31580020c0] missing picture in access unit with size 1853721
[AVBSFContext @ 0x7f3158009500] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.

```
Last message repeated 648 times
```

[AVBSFContext @ 0x7f3158009500] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.=0/0
    Last message repeated 1924 times

[h264 @ 0x7f31580020c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 130 times

[h264 @ 0x7f31580020c0] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.    0B f=0/0
    Last message repeated 2442 times

[h264 @ 0x7f31580020c0] no frame!

[h264 @ 0x7f3158000940] decoding for stream 0 failed

[h264 @ 0x7f3158000940] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size

Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'H264-media-4.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc

[h264 @ 0x7f3158003700] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
    Last message repeated 2573 times

[h264 @ 0x7f3158003700] no frame!

The file H264-media-4.264 is not played even with VLC on windows.

Comment: use elecard (https://www.elecard.com) or codecvisa (http://www.codecian.com/) to play .264 file.

Comment: Is there also a previous `H264-media-1` etc, up to `H264-media-3`? Do any of those work?

Comment: No. None of them. But rest of the files have less size, that's why I've posted result of third file

Comment: I suspect they have _"less size"_ because they hold the metadata (SPS and PPS) needed to decode the video properly. You need to re-join all those `.264` bytes together as one long file. You could try joining bytes with a hex editor (or maybe even FFmpeg's own `concat` option might work). If using hex editor to test... Just open H264-media-1.264 and scroll down to bytes ending where you then copy/paste the next `.264` file's bytes into that ending (now is longer file). After pasting the bytes of H264-media-4.264, save as `Test.264` then try to see if VLC shows a picture when you load that.

Comment: PS: If possible then please provide the 3 files for our problem checking. If trying hex editor yourself on Windows then I recommend [HxD Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD20).

Comment: after analyzing videosnarf console statements, for each protocol and direction it is creating one file. I'm new to this tool and to my surprise even for DNS and AMR-WB codecs(audio call associated with mentioned video call) also it is creating files with extension H264-media-*.264 extension. One more observation is if I pass "-c" for videosnarf all generated files of size 0. Where as the file generated for receiving stream was played properly. I suspect problem might be with Tx packetization format as for rx stream it is generating only one file and it was played well